# Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript, generics, arguments, default

How do I fix this error?

```
function get<T extends Element>(
    selector: string,
    type: new () => T = HTMLElement, // Error on this line
): T {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (elements.length === 1) {
        const element = elements.item(0);
        if (element instanceof type) {
            return element;
        }
        throw 'Wrong type';
    } else if (elements.length === 0) {
        throw `No element was found: ${selector}`;
    } else {
        throw `Non-unique result: ${selector}`;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQDwBVGoB5SpgAmAzogKIA2qAtkVAHwAUAUIh4qajdHAE4AuLlH4wwyADTtOUAJ4AHVMLCoA7omYBKRAF5GiHLsQAJLAFkAMtToNpW4TgDeMjhASkouGvTBRyxsRwECC+UAB0AI4gqPxyAMo8qHz8AIJUVMzcvFACWgDcrogwwJpJYaThNBJQABZ6usYAjDounO2I7mCe3rZ+er0V4TCEtMwADAVF7SVlPgzF3VAAhpCocKXySq3THRz86CD8SOUMhXscAL67HHX8cBoA5ADq9xKIW6iP55yX3tzFUrMU5+SrVZB1BrGSaINoXO4PRAAAwAcnBBgs1MtyMA4OBiMIACRObLJXL8S5In5Xf6oWE3D61e4aVEIAC04Bg0TpB1IICoUCJJKSKUp1MQ10uQA)

```
Type '{ new (): HTMLElement; prototype: HTMLElement; }' is not assignable to type 'new () => T'.
  Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'HTMLElement' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Element'.
```

Comment: Have you carefully read the error message?

Comment: In particular, this part: `'HTMLElement' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Element'.`

Comment: What do intend to do if someone calls `get<HTMLDivElement>('foo')`?

Comment: I had no idea this syntax exists: `get<HTMLDivElement>('foo')`. That error makes sense now.

I was under impression that T could only be defined by the 2nd argument.

But I am still left with the problem of not being able to use a generic default argument. Any solutions for that?

Comment: Please see the answer to the linked question for more information.